# Unity Coin Collect Photon Pun 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I am trying to create a system for players to collect coins, if the coins have been collected then the key will spawn, but I have a problem when the player collects coins, namely when the first coin is destroyed then the photon view on the coin is destroyed, and when the second coin wants to be collected the player then the photon view has been destroyed. How, I made the coin destroyed but the photon view was not destroyed?
This is the error :  Illegal view ID:0 method: CollectCoin GO:Coin (2)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)

```
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class Coin : MonoBehaviourPun
{

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Player collided with coin");
            if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
            {
                photonView.RPC("CollectCoin", RpcTarget.All, other.gameObject.GetComponent<PhotonView>().ViewID);
            }
        }
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void CollectCoin(int playerViewID)
    {
        CoinCollect playerCoinCollection = PhotonView.Find(playerViewID).gameObject.GetComponent<CoinCollect>();

        string playerName = PhotonView.Find(playerViewID).gameObject.name;

        // playerCoinCollection.CollectCoin(playerName);
        photonView.RPC("DeactivateCoin", RpcTarget.All);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    void DeactivateCoin()
    {
         PhotonNetwork.Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class CoinCollect : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks, IPunObservable
{
    public GameObject keyPrefab;
    private int coinCount;
    private int playerCount;
    private int coinsNeeded;

    void Start()
    {
        playerCount = PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length; 

        switch (playerCount)
    {
        case 1:
            coinsNeeded = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            coinsNeeded = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            coinsNeeded = 15;
            break;
        case 4:
            coinsNeeded = 20;
            break;
        default:
            Debug.LogError("Unsupported player count: " + playerCount);
            break;
    }
    }

    // Trigger when player collects coin
    public void CollectCoin()
    {
        coinCount++;
        CheckCoinCount();
    }

    private void CheckCoinCount()
    {
        if (coinCount >= coinsNeeded)
        {
            SpawnKey();
        }
    }

    private void SpawnKey()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(keyPrefab.name, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }

    public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        if (stream.IsWriting)
        {
            stream.SendNext(coinCount);
        }
        else
        {
            this.coinCount = (int)stream.ReceiveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the `DeactivateCoin()` method, which is calling `PhotonNetwork.Destroy`.
`PhotonNetwork.Destroy` gets called on all clients.  However, you are also calling it from every client via RPC.
Eventually a client will call this and the view is already destroyed, which I believe is where the exception is coming from.

Instead, have a single client (the master client or the client collecting the coin) call `PhotonNetwork.Destroy`.
No RPC needed here for the destroy.